# How to find all subarrays whose bitwise 'AND' lies in a given range?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given an array `A` of integers,we are required to find subarrays ,the bitwise `&` of whose elements lie in a given range `low` to `high` where

`low < min(A[0],A[1]....A[n-1])`

and

`high = min(A[0],A[1]..A[n-1])`

i.e. Find all `{i,j}` such that `low <= A[i]&A[i+1]&...&A[j] <=high`

I have thought about this for a long time but can't seem to come up with anything except the naive implementation of generating all subarrays.

Can there be an asymptotically better solution for this?

Comment: did you mean `high > max(A[0], A[1], ... ,A[n-1])` ?

Comment: The first optimization is to realize that ANDing the next element into an existing result can only reduce the result or leave it the same. It can never increase the result. So as soon as the result falls below `low`, you can stop.

Comment: @Yidna No,the range lies between 0 and minimum array element.Besides high can not exceed the maximum element of A anyway,since bitwise `and` of subarrays would have an upper bound of the maximum element in the subarray.

Comment: @user3386109,used that,but it still doesn't help the worst case asymptotic complexity though :(

Comment: Doesn't this shout *dynamic programming*? Whether or not anything changes *asymptotic complexity* depends on the complexity model, too: with output size potentially dominating *n*, arguing about [output-sensitive algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm) looks smart.

Comment: It seems like the output of an array of length `n` with all `1`s in it and bounds of `0` and `2`, will be asymptotically `n^3` - [calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i*(n-i)+i+goes+from+1+to+n). So maybe the naive solution of generating all sub arrays isn't so bad...

Comment: Cf. [How to find all subarrays whose bitwise and lies in a given range?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/106896/19966).